# how to put a file having several records into an array in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to put a file into an array and save it in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639812/how-to-put-a-file-into-an-array-and-save-it-in-perl)

I am a beginner in perl and I want to put my file with records in to an array from AA to / in each array element. So could anyone please help me out.

My INPUT FILE is like this:

\

AA  c0001

BB  afsfjgfjgjgjflffbg

CC  table

DD  hhhfsegsksgk

EB  jksgksjs
\

AA  e0002

BB  rejwkghewhgsejkhrj

CC  chair

DD  egrhjrhojohkhkhrkfs

VB  rkgjehkrkhkh;r

\

this is a txt file format so, from this file I am supposed to collect all the information starting from AA to \ for each of the things like 'table' is there in ist record also 'chair' is there in the 2nd record and I need to collect all the records having 'CC  table'   and 'CC  chair' as they are randomly arranged in whole file also there are about hundreds of records for these table and chair that I need to collect. So I would like to put my file into an array first having each of its element from AA to . Is there is any other idea to do this thing. Could someone help me in writing code for making an array.I'll be highly thankful.

Comment: yes I know but I'm not getting anything out of that.

Comment: soniya: you need to show what you want the data to look like afterwards.  or if you don't know, you need to show how you want to use the data afterwards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639812/how-to-put-a-file-into-an-array-and-save-it-in-perl You were given a very good answer on a very similar question before.

Comment: I am sorry to say but as i am a beginner I don't know a way out to make this into an array I have explained everything in the paragraph mentioned below input file. Please suggest anything for that. Thanks

Comment: mugen kenichi I tried the previous solution but now there is some different problem that i am facing. Please take a look on my question again as I need to make a new file having all the records for chair, table and other things present in it. So I am putting them into array and further need to shortlist only those arrays elements which are having just chair records and just table records. Please suggest a solution for this. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am surprised this question is still open. Even if it is not a duplicate, surely it is not the SO policy to write the entire code for people?

Comment: @soniya: I see your problem is different but i dont see what you tried to achieve your goal.. you dont provide any code so one could get the impression you dont work with the solutions given to you. What you ask is to write the code for you..

Comment: Sure, I'll show you my code soon. Thanks for all the help. I'm apologized for not providing the code. I'll post it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are looking for specific strings, a regex is your best bet.  A regex is short way of telling Perl what sort of string you are looking for.  It also lets you capture parts of the string so you don't have to extract them later.

Your case is complicated by the fact that your record stretches across many lines, but regexes can handle than with the `\m` option.  It makes `^` and `$` match beginning-of-line and end-of-line instead of beginning-of-string and end-of-string.  This means you can say

```
my ($type) = $record =~ /^CC (.+)/m;
```

The `^` matches the beginning of a line, `C` matches the literal C, the space matches a literal space, the parentheses don't match anything (they start a capture group), the `.` matches any character but a newline, and the `+` says match says match one or more of the preceding thing (i.e. the `.`).

This regex is applied to the string in `$record` by the `=~` operator.

Matches that are in list context return their capture groups, so by putting `$type` in parentheses, we make the match return the capture group into the `$type` variable.  Once we have access to the type of the record, a simple if statement allows us to filter the records however you wish:

```
if ($type eq "chair") {
    #do chair stuff
} elsif ($type eq "table") {
    #do table stuff
} else {
    die "I don't know what to do with '$type'";
}
```

If you are using Perl 5.10 or later and have the [`feature`](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html) pragma turned on, you can use the `given`/`when` syntax this is a lot nicer for this sort of logic:

```
given ($type) {
    when ("chair") {
        #do chair stuff
    }
    when ("table") {
        #do table stuff
    }
    default {
        die "I don't know what to do with '$type'";
    }
}
```

You can read more about regexes in [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) and [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: thanks a lot Chas Owens. I will try it and let you know if there will be any problem.Again Thankyou.